# Error - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-udb1b)

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question, but next time you need to include the relevant code in your question, not just link to an external project because that makes it much harder and more time consuming for us to look through your code. Lucky for you, your code was minimal, so I was able to find the problem

The issue you're facing is here:

```
const Text = children => {
  return <span style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>{children}</span>;
};
```

`children` in react is a prop that's automatically passed inside an object to components. So to access it you need to change your text 'dumb' component to this:

```
const Text = ({children}) => {
  return <span style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>{children}</span>;
};
```

this will allow your component to get the `props` object, and destructure the `children` field out of it